# Как группировать массив данных в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Есть массив данных в JavaScript. Надо группировать их по свойству. Например, есть массив сотрудников:

```
employees = [
   {
    id: 111,
    name: 'Ivan',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01' 
   },
   {
    id: 222,
    name: 'Oleg',
    salary: 3000,
    date: '2020-01-01' 
   },
   {
    id: 111,
    name: 'Ivan',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01' 
   },
   {
    id: 333,
    name: 'Anya',
    salary: 3000,
    date: '2020-01-02' 
   },
   {
    id: 444,
    name: 'Arman',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01' 
   }
  ]
```

Теперь их надо группировать, типа:

```
obj = {
  '2020-01-01' : {
   111: {
      "salary": 5000
    
   },
  }
}
```

Comment: В примере двe одинаковых даты с одинаковыми id... должно стать salary: 10000 ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dosxanzada/pen/oNbOEme?editors=1111

Comment: я тут замутил сам "алгоритм" xD. теперь хочу сделать по короче, используя map, reduce, filter, если возможно? я еще плохо знаю их

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если по двум параметрам группировать, то можно так. Если больше, то переписал бы в рекурсивное построение дерева с последующим заполнением.

```js
let employees = [{
    id: 111,
    name: 'Ivan',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 222,
    name: 'Oleg',
    salary: 3000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 111,
    name: 'Ivan',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 333,
    name: 'Anya',
    salary: 3000,
    date: '2020-01-02'
  },
  {
    id: 444,
    name: 'Arman',
    salary: 5000,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  }
];
let groupResult = employees.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.date] = obj[item.date] || {};
  (obj[item.date][item.id] = obj[item.date][item.id] || []).push({
    id: item.id,
    name: item.name,
    date: item.date,
    salary: item.salary
  });
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(groupResult);
```

Comment: тут в результате некоторые записи удаляются же? мне надо как бы сгруппировать по дате, типа в этот день эти сотрудники получили з/п, (надо учитывать если один сотрудник получит несколько раз)

Comment: https://github.com/dosxanzada/dosxanzada.github.io/blob/master/final-work.js

я замутил так, теперь хочу избавляться от for, if. но пока еще не знаю как грамотно использовать reduce, map, filter

Comment: Переделал как в примере по ссылке выше.

Answer (score 0):

Если просто как получить подобную структуру. То можно так.Используя этот принцип можно в цикле перебрать все employees.Просто об этом в вопросе речь вроде не шла.

```
employees = [
    {
        id: 111,
        name: 'Ivan',
        salary: 5000,
        date: '2020-01-01'
    },
    {
        id: 222,
        name: 'Oleg',
        salary: 3000,
        date: '2020-01-01'
    },
    {
        id: 111,
        name: 'Ivan',
        salary: 5000,
        date: '2020-01-01'
    },
    {
        id: 333,
        name: 'Anya',
        salary: 3000,
        date: '2020-01-02'
    },
    {
        id: 444,
        name: 'Arman',
        salary: 5000,
        date: '2020-01-01'
    }
]

let date = employees[0].date;
let id = employees[0].id;
let salary = employees[0].salary;


obj = {
    [date] : {
        [id]: {
            "salary": salary
        },
    }
}

console.log(obj)
```